# How do you set basic keyboard shortcuts in Qt Creator?

Tags: editor, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

Can I assign ctrl+p to move a line up like the up arrow, for example?
Or ctrl+f to act like the right arrow?

It seems like the most basic keyboard shortcuts are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your keyboard shortcuts in: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, including import a set of new shortcuts.